# How to not show Visual Studio 2013 floating doc icons in taskbar?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, taskbar, floating

I am using VS 2013 Express, desktop.
I regularly tear off doc tabs and put a doc on my other monitor.
That adds an icon to the windows taskbar for each floating doc.
How would I stop that? Its very wasteful of space as I do not "combine" icons on taskbar (and never will).
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is Windows behavior rather than VS-specific behavior and you can see it in other applications as well (e.g. Google Chrome, error pop-ups in some apps, etc.) and it has a simple rationale behind it to allow the user to easily switch between the application windows. This makes a lot of sense as otherwise you'll have to mess with many windows in order to unhide the window you'd like to work with.

I'm unaware of a way to change this behavior of Windows and per the above I tend to believe that this is intentionally not possible.

Comment: hmm, VS 2010 did not do this. very confusing for progs that naturally have several documents involved at once.